# Jpgraph : database data can't insert to the bar chart using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, jpgraph

here is my code :

```
<?php 
// content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php');
include("mysql _connect .php");

$code="CSC1113";
$ac_yr="2010/2011";
$sql = "SELECT results, COUNT(*) 'No_Of_grades' FROM std_results WHERE code='$code' && ac_year='$ac_yr' GROUP BY results ORDER BY results ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($ors = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $grd=$ors['results'];
    switch ($grd)
{
case "A":
  $datay[1]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
case "A+":
  $datay[0]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
case "A-":
  $datay=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "B":
  $datay[4]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "B+":
  $datay[3]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "B-":
  $datay[5]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
 case "C":
  $datay[7]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "C+":
  $datay[6]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "C-":
  $datay[8]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "D":
  $datay[10]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "D+":
  $datay[9]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "E":
  $datay[11]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "AB":
  $datay[12]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "NE":
  $datay[13]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
default:
  $datay[14]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
}

    }

    //set vlaue zero for othe grades..
    for($i=0;$i<15;$i++){
        if(!isset($datay[$i])){
            $datay[$i]=0;
            }

        }


// Create the graph. These two calls are always required
$graph = new Graph(550,320,'auto');
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

//$theme_class="DefaultTheme";
//$graph->SetTheme(new $theme_class());

// set major and minor tick positions manually
$graph->yaxis->SetTickPositions(array(0,4,8,12,16,20), array(2,6,10,14,18));
$graph->SetBox(false);

//$graph->ygrid->SetColor('gray');
$graph->ygrid->SetFill(false);
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('A+','A','A-','B+','B','B-','C+','C','C-','D+','D','E','AB','NE','MC'));
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);

// Create the bar plots
$b1plot = new BarPlot($datay);

// ...and add it to the graPH
$graph->Add($b1plot);


$b1plot->SetColor("white");
$b1plot->SetFillGradient("#4B0082","white",GRAD_LEFT_REFLECTION);
$b1plot->SetWidth(25);
$graph->title->Set("Bar Gradient(Left reflection)");

// Display the graph
$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

here jpgrpah doesn't display..error shows : **JpGraph Error: 25067 Your manually specified scale and ticks is not correct. The scale seems to be too small to hold any of the specified tick marks.**
but I gave direct  data for above $datay array.this code is working perfectly..like this

```
$datay[0]=2;
$datay[1]=5;
$datay[2]=1;
$datay[3]=2;
$datay[4]=0;
$datay[5]=0;
$datay[6]=3;
$datay[7]=0;
$datay[8]=3;
$datay[9]=0;
$datay[10]=1;
$datay[11]=1;
$datay[12]=0;
$datay[13]=1;
$datay[14]=1;
```

wht's the wrong with my code ....can't understand....help me...thanxx in advanced...

Comment: here is my table : http://i.imgur.com/qcTQL.png

Comment: What is this : 'No_Of_grades' ?

Comment: one column name I get fron above sql query ...see this imgage : http://i.imgur.com/YjJbr.png

Comment: code looks okay problem is in query " i think" . Also you should look into MYSQLI or PDO, Mysql has been deprciated and will not be used in future versions. What is the name of the table that 'No_Of_grades' comes from.

Comment: no dear No_Of_grades is the name of the column it's frm COUNT(*) 'No_Of_grades'...dear this sql query is ok..it has no problem..problem is can not inert dat to this grpagh it shows error :JpGraph Error: 25067 Your manually specified scale and ticks is not correct. The scale seems to be too small to hold any of the specified tick marks.

Comment: 'No_Of_grades' is not in your first table that you listed. You cannot pull from two different tables in this manner.

Comment: reason you are getting that error is because the query is not filling the array, but when you manually fill it, the code works. Therefor the query is not working.

Comment: no dear sql query is working...when i put this code in mysql query "SELECT results, COUNT(*) 'No_Of_grades' FROM std_results WHERE code='CSC1113' GROUP BY results ORDER BY results ASC;" out put is http://i.imgur.com/YjJbr.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think now that i understand you :

```
case "A-":
  $datay=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
```

should be:

```
case "A-":
  $datay['2']=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
```